How to download assembly code to arduino uno board using avrdude, preserving the bootloader?
I have a arduino uno board with bootloader. It's working with Arduino IDE, without any issues.
I would like to download a simple assembly program to it using avrdude without affecting the bootloader. So, when the mcu comes out of reset, it runs my program (probably after bootloader timeout). Also, I should be able to download programs, as usual, in future using avrdude through bootloader.
This is the program:
    .global main

    .text
    .org 0
main:
    ldi r21, 8
loop: dec r21
    brne loop

stay: rjmp stay

My question is: with .org 0 assembler directive is it safe to download it with avrdude without overwriting the bootloader?
If this won't work, what changes are needed to the assembly code?
BTW, I'm using xc8 toolchain.
Also, I'm looking for a solution does NOT use Arduino IDE or its toolchain.

EDIT: I would like to run avrdude in windows machine connected to arduino uno board using usb cable, without any programmer (similar to what arduino ide does).

Arduino uses avrdude too, just turn on the verbose upload in settings and copy the command.

Thanks @KIIV, I could get the command to upload hex file to arduino board using avrdude. The upload preserved bootloader as expected. There is a nice write up here with clear explanation.
